# Meteor mongodb: how to get the N th records?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I can't find anywhere it has been documented this. By default, the find() operation will get the records from beginning. How can I get the  N th records in meteor mongodb?
for eg : i want to second last record !!

Comment: do you know limit property ? See the doc available in http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-find. Let me know if you have some questions.

Comment: ya ..i know but meteor is it possible???

Comment: yes it is. you just have to pass `{limit : N}` as options parameter.

Comment: ok.. thanks so much.. i use skip method

Comment: Ah i thought that you wanted to limit the number of records.. I will put an answer accordingly.

Comment: one more question,kindly please.. how to meteor application start mongo collection clear all collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the skip option as described [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-find).

Try the following code:

```
CollectionName.find({...}, {skip : N});
```